# Remap Keyboard Keys Windows 7 on the fly

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, hotkeys, remapping

I am working on a software project where I run an Adobe air project in fullscreen on laptops. I would like to avoid keys and combinations that would bring any other things to the front. So I would like to disable those normal Windows 7 keys like <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>, Windows KEY, Function keys, Shift key and especially those FN Keys to mute or reduce the display brightness.

Now comes the point through a secret key combination (for example "admin") you can leave the air application - and then you should get you normal keys back. So without reboot or logon log off. My first idea was to create to different keyboard layouts for Windows (these can switch on the fly)

Does someone know a suitable way? This is a active project so I have a budget if someone you help me on this issue...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to [compile](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) a script which disables certain [key combinations](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) and have a "toggle" keyboard shortcut which [suspends](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm) the script (thereby enabling the keys).

Here is a simple example:

```
^+F12:: ;[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[F12]
    Suspend, Toggle
    return

Alt & Tab:: 
LWin::
RWin::
Escape::
    ;do nothing
    return
```